Why when building image for backend it cannot connect to mysql
When i use docker compose up for building all service and run when building stage backend(spring-boot) cannot connect MySQL database it cannot build and run image for backend.
I try to set all service is in same network but it not working
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: database.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql@sit
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysql-lib:/var/lib/mysql
      # - ./database/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
      # - ./database/setup/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
    - test-networks
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - database
      
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql@sit
      - MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/task_base?serverTimezone=UTC
    networks:
      - test-networks

networks:
  test-networks:
    driver: bridge


Here is my Dockerfile (backend)
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17
COPY . /backendAPI
WORKDIR /backendAPI
RUN mvn clean package
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/backendAPI/target/*.jar"]


dockerfile for database
FROM mysql/mysql-server:latest
COPY ./my.cnf /etc/
VOLUME ./mysql-lib /var/lib/mysql
COPY ./setup/db-script-v2.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENV  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql@sit

My project structure
ITB-KK-Backend
├─ .mvn
│  └─ wrapper
│     ├─ maven-wrapper.jar
│     └─ maven-wrapper.properties
├─ database
│  ├─ database.Dockerfile
│  ├─ my.cnf
│  └─ setup
│     └─ db-script-v2.sql
├─ docker-compose.yaml
├─ Dockerfile
├─ mvnw
├─ mvnw.cmd
├─ pom.xml
└─ src
   ├─ main

My application.properties (spring-boot config file)
spring.application.name=ITB-KK
spring.datasource.username={MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.password={MYSQL_PASSWORD:123456}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_URL:localhost}:3306/task_base?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.main.banner-mode=off
server.servlet.context-path=/itb-kk
#spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
server.error.include-stacktrace=never

but when i run compose up it error
309.6 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
309.6
309.6 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
309.6   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
309.6   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
309.6   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
309.6   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
309.6   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
309.6   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
309.6   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]  
309.6   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:428) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
309.6   at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6

I want can build docker image for backend successfully i dont know why it cannot

MySQL can take time to start up, you should add a healthcheck and a condition to your depends_on

Does this answer your question? Docker-compose check if mysql connection is ready

If your error happens at build time, then the database is not available. The database container is only started at run-time. This often causes issues with ORMs and stuff like Next.js that want to access databases at build time. I don't know of an easy solution other than to manually run the database and build the image using plain Docker. That is, not using docker compose for building.

There is an ENTRY in logs in Eclipse and there ENTRYPOINT in Docker.

After looking at your repository, https://github.com/22p21s0045/Fix-spring-deploy.git, it became apparent that the error is indeed happening at build time. The question is a little misleading because it mentions that the error occurs "when i run compose up", which suggests that it is a runtime error.
With additional context it appears that the error is being caused by the tests in src/test/java/sit/int221/ItbKkApplicationTests.java. Those tests appear to be trying to connect to a database and the way that this is currently set up there will be no database for them to connect to.
You have a few options including:

Delete or disable the tests (temporarily) just to get it to build. I removed src/test/java/sit/int221/ItbKkApplicationTests.java and could then run docker-compose build && docker-compose up.
Ensure that there is a database available at build time for the tests to use.

Here's the additional context that indicates that it's a testing error:
13.13 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                    
13.13 [INFO]  T E S T S                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
13.13 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                    
13.41 [INFO] Running sit.int221.ItbKkApplicationTests                                                                                                                                                                                   
13.55 08:13:43.329 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [sit.int221.ItbKkApplicationTests]: ItbKkApplicationTests do
es not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.                                                                                                                                        
13.55 08:13:43.378 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration sit.int221.ItbKkApplication for test class sit.int221.ItbKkApplicationTests                    
13.65 08:13:43.448 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener -- Restart disabled due to context in which it is running                                                                           
13.75 2024-04-26T08:13:43.584Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] sit.int221.ItbKkApplicationTests         : Starting ItbKkApplicationTests using Java 17.0.1 with PID 120 (started by root in /backendAPI)                       
13.75 2024-04-26T08:13:43.585Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] sit.int221.ItbKkApplicationTests         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"                                                  
14.15 2024-04-26T08:13:43.971Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.                                                          
14.25 2024-04-26T08:13:44.001Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 26 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.                                 
14.45 2024-04-26T08:13:44.271Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]                                                            
14.45 2024-04-26T08:13:44.294Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final                                                                    
14.55 2024-04-26T08:13:44.313Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled                                                                               
14.65 2024-04-26T08:13:44.416Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer                                                              
14.65 2024-04-26T08:13:44.430Z  INFO 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...                                                                                           
15.65 2024-04-26T08:13:45.490Z ERROR 120 --- [ITB-KK] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.                                                                 
15.65                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
15.65 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure                                                                                                                                                 
15.65                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
15.65 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.


I'd recommend avoiding a database dependency for your tests if at all possible.  Can you write a mock around your data-access layer, or use an in-memory database like H2 or HDBC?  You also may be able to skip the tests during the image build; see for example Docker and mvn build - cant pass unit tests as DB needs another container running?

SQLite might be another option for the tests?

Update your docker-compose.yml to something like this:
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: database.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql@sit
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysql-lib:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
    - test-networks
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  backend:
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql@sit
      - MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/task_base?serverTimezone=UTC
    networks:
      - test-networks

networks:
  test-networks:
    driver: bridge

Important changes:

Add healthcheck to the database service. The service will only be marked as "healthy" once mysqladmin is able to get a successful ping, which indicates that the database is ready.
Update the depends_on for the backend service to depend on the condition that the database service has been marked as "healthy".


Thank for answer but i try to do this but it not working
I try to push this project to github .
https://github.com/22p21s0045/Fix-spring-deploy.git

Can you be more specific about "but it not working"? Are you seeing the same error? The repository that you have linked to does not have health checks in the docker-compose.yaml file.

Yes i got the same error

I think error is happen in build stage when docker try to build image from Dockerfile
